# undefined is not an object (evaluating RNGestureHandlerModule.State)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a stack navigator and it gives me the above mentioned error. My code as bellow

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
 import NavigationService from './Utils/NavigationService'
 import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
 import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
 import { createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; 
 import Stat from './App/statsScreen'
 import Sec from './App/loginScreen'


const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
   Home: Stat,
   Details: Sec
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Details"
  }
 );

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
 {

  App: RootStack,

 }, {
 initialRouteName: 'App'
 }
);

export const store = (__DEV__) ? createStore(rootReducer, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk), window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f)) : createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default class App extends React.Component {

 render() {
   return (
    <Provider store={store}>
     <AppNavigator
      ref={navigatorRef => {
        NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
      }}
     />
    </Provider>
   );
 }

}
```

However If I comment the "createStackNavigator" part and export a general class it works. What am I missing here? and with this code why is it trowing me an error like that ?